# Pandas DataFrame drop row

Tags: pandas

```
            total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2013-07-02            29624840
2013-07-03            22525940
2013-07-04            32111643
...                        ...
```

I need to drop the 2 row `(2013-07-02    29624840)`，How can I do that?

Comment: See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop` method

```
In [8]: df.drop(['2013-07-02'])
Out[8]:
            total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2013-07-03            22525940
2013-07-04            32111643
```

Here initial `df` was

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
            total_purchase_amt
2013-07-01            22533121
2013-07-02            29624840
2013-07-03            22525940
2013-07-04            32111643
```

Comment: Error:ValueError: labels ['2013-07-02'] not contained in axis

Comment: what is your type(df) and type(df.index[0]) ? In my example it was dataframe and str.

Comment: type(df) is dataframe, type(df.index[0]) == pandas.tslib.Timestamp

Comment: Ah, then try converting it to time object like `df.drop([pd.to_datetime('2013-07-02')])` or any other date conversion method.